# Executing code inside the while expression statement

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, tryparse

```
        int VillainId = -1;
        Console.Write("Enter VillainId: ");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out VillainId))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a valid Villain Id!");
            Console.Write("Enter VillainId: ");
        }
```

Can someone tell me how the code inside the `while(**this code here**){//rest of the code}` works. I understand if it was inside the {} but its in the condition and its looping until it successfully parses a number. How does that work ?

Comment: `int.TryParse` returns true if it successfully parses the string it's getting from Console.ReadLine(). The `!` in front of it means to reverse the bool, so the `while` executes the code in the parens, and if `int.TryParse` returns false, the `while` execute again -- and again and again, until `int.TryParse` returns true.

Comment: so if i understand correctly if its false it does the work in the {} then check again and by that you mean it runs the whole try.parse again and if successful outs the int and returns true ?

Comment: That's right, every time it goes again, it calls `Console.ReadLine()` all over again for new input, passes that to `int.TryParse()` which tries to parse the new value, etc., until the parse is successful and it breaks out of the loop. A [do/while loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is another way to write that code, and might be easier to get your head around.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the first line and then step through the programm. You will see what is executed and when it is executed.

Comment: Thank you now i understand and its not "black magic" anymore :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int.TryParse` returns true if it successfully parses the string it's getting from `Console.ReadLine()`. The `!` in front of it means to reverse the boolean value returned by `int.TryParse`, so the `while` executes the code in the parens, and if `int.TryParse` returns false, the false gets reversed to a `true` and the while executes again -- and again and again, until `int.TryParse` returns true. "The while executes" means the code in the parens executes first, and then if the result of that is `true`, the body of the while executes as well.

Here's another way to write the same code. It's a little less compact, but might be easier to follow:

```
int VillainId = -1;
bool parseOK = false;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter VillainId: ");

    parseOK = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out VillainId);

    if (!parseOK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a valid Villain Id!");
    }
} while (! parseOK);
```

Answer (score 2):

`int.TryParse()` returns `true` if the conversion was successful and the [**`!`** (logical negation operator)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx) inverts the `boolean` value in his right side (`!true` is equals to `false`).

The condition in `while` **is evaluated every loop**, so, every invalid input the block code in `while()` will be executed.

The flow is, basically:

```
Console.Write("Enter VillainId: ");
// asks to user input

while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out VillainId))
// while the conversion is not successfull
{
    Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a valid Villain Id!");
    Console.Write("Enter VillainId: ");
    // asks for user to input valid data
}
```

Comment: that i understand, what confuses me is does the while loop execute the try.parse each time it check for the condition ?

Comment: @StoyanGrigorov Run the code and find out for yourself.

Comment: After reading  Ed Plunkett's comments i understand now how it works clearly. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: @StoyanGrigorov Edited